# iPhone shows up in Image Capture, but not in iTunes

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, backup

I'm trying to backup my iPhone 6s running iOS 12.1, using iTunes on a 13" 2012 MBP running OSX 10.12.

I recently updated the iPhone from either iOS 10 or 11 (I can't recall which version,) to backup via iTunes it said I needed to update the version of iOS to do so.

The iPhone shows up fine in the Image Capture app, but doesn't appear in iTunes (see attached screenshot). The phone also doesn't show up in iTunes if I go to File > Devices.

I also have iCloud backup set up on the iPhone, but I wanted a physical copy on my HD.

Any ideas why its not showing up in iTunes ?

[image: screenshot showing iTunes window and Image Capture window]

Comment: If you click on the iTunes menu > About iTunes, what version of iTunes does it say? The current version is 12.8

Comment: @kelly im running iTunes 12.8.0150

Comment: @Kelly whats really strange is i plugged in the iphone today and despite it running iOS 12.1 (16b92) i got a message saying in order to connect the iPhone to the computer the iPhone needs to be updated, see screenshot here : https://imgur.com/a/fpOrmwe - Im running the update now.. ill let you know how i get on